# Display StringLength message for NOT REQUIRED case

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a @Html.TextBoxFor control with @Html.ValidationMessageFor, which is not a Required Field, but there is a limit in Maximum Length and also only numbers should be permitted. I have given the following code in the ViewModel :

```
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The field Phone must have a maximum length of 10")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
```

**On the button click, I am unable to retrieve the above validation message while I had entered more than 10 characters.**

And also How will I validate whether numeric ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller action that you are posting to must take the view model containing the `Phone` property as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

or if this is not the case you should call the `UpdateModel` or `TryUpdateModel` methods inside to invoke the default model binder which is responsible for calling the validation logic and inserting any potential error messages into the ModelState.

> And also How will I validate whether numeric ?

You could use a Regex:

```
[StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The field Phone must have a maximum length of 10")]
[RegularExpression(@"\d*", ErrorMessage = "The field Phone must contain only digits")]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "yourmessage")]
public string Phone
```

But you can fix it with a regular expression as well,
just google "phone + regex". Pretty sure you can validate on maxlength using regexAttr